# How do I make a view that waits for a background process to complete, then redirects to a confirmation action

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am busy writing code to use a third party service to process payments.  A very short wait after the user submits their payment, the service calls a URL on my site to send a payment confirmation message.  I want to display a view that informs the user I am waiting for this message, and then redirects to the next step in my sign-up process.

How can I go about this?  The simplest that comes to mind is using a **JavaScriptResult**, which returns null while the process is still busy, and then returns redirection code when the process has completed.  Is this a a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a View that contains JavaScript which polls a service with Ajax calls. In the meantime you would display a spinner or similar item.

As soon as the Ajax call returns "success", your JavaScript method then redirects to the "Success" page.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I'm doing, but I don't know how to do any of that.

Comment: Aw man, I totally forgot about jQuery ajax.  That I know how to do, thanks.